# Keyboard hide UITextView swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I m using `UITableView` with 2 customs cells, I have custom cells with `UITextView` and `UITextField`, I'm trying to move up the edited field when it's hiding by the keyboard on the top of the keyboard, here is my code for the `viewDidLoad` :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

    }
```

and here the function called when keyboard notification is sent :

```
func adjustForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification {
        myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        print("ZERO")
    } else {
        myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = myTableView.contentInset
}
```

It's working perfectly for the `UITextField` but not for the `UITextView`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Steve ([dismiss keyboard with a uiTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600359/dismiss-keyboard-with-a-uitextview))

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```