# ios: while editing in textview, keyboard return key not working

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
   if text == "\n" {
       tempDescription = txteditdescription.text
       txteditdescription.resignFirstResponder()
       return false
   }
   return true
}
```

i'm new in ios developement
it is my string variable -> "tempDescription" i want store edited text in string variable on keyboard return key.

it is my textview -> "txteditdescription"
     but through above method my simulator keyboard not hide.
so what i have to do ? 
Thanks

Comment: pls visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600359/dismiss-keyboard-with-a-uitextview

Comment: posted my answer below @hardik

Answer (score 0):

Drag from your textfield to the viewcontroller it's connected to, and create an action event called 'Did End On Exit', and call it whatever you want.

[image]

Then inside of the function, call

```
self.resignFirstResponder()
```

like this

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the delegate like this.

```
txteditdescription.delegate = self
```

Then implement the delegate method shouldChangeTextInRange

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n") {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```