# Hiding keyboard after hitting the Done key - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

so I am making a textfield programmatically. When I hit the done key in the keyboard the curser goes to the next line and key board does not disappear. I have included all the lines of codes recommened by people to make the keyboard disappear but it didn't work. can someone look at my code and advice me what I need to add? I want to hit the done key and keyboard disappear and curser doesn't go to the next line.

```
import UIKit

class FirstPage: UIViewController {

    let emailText: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray])
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textView.attributedText = attributedText
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.returnKeyType = .done
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return textView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emailText.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate
        view.addSubview(emailText)
        emailText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        emailText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you conform to UITextViewDelegate from your viewcontroller class decleration and then update the delegate setting in your viewDidLoad as: emailText.delegate = self, then Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600359/dismiss-keyboard-with-a-uitextview

Comment: I added the two functions to my code (func textView) but it did not work :(

Comment: I have seen all those question and I added all the lines of codes they recommended but I still can't make it work

Comment: @Sara did you add delegate method to your code? I can't see any

Comment: I have in another code. in this one I forgot. I just added it and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: can you copy paste my code into your Xcode and see how it acts in the simultaor?

Comment: It makes no sense to use a text view if you can only enter one line of text. Use a UITextField if you only want one line of text.

Comment: @rmaddy that's right, I didn't pay attention on text which he's setting.

Comment: Why did you delete the answer? it worked! I was trying to mark it as answered!

Comment: so you guys are saying I should not use uitextview?

Comment: Correct. A `UITextView` is for entering multiple lines of text. A `UITextField` is for when you only want a single line of text.

Comment: “so I am making a textfield” No you’re not. You are making a text view, a very different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your comments, I believe that you have delegate method for dismissing keyboard.

First problem which I see is that you view controller doesn't implement text view's delegate protocol, change it: `Class: Protocol`

```
extension FirstPage: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

then set delegate of your text view just as `self`

```
emailText.delegate = self
```

Also make your text view variable `lazy` (also you can assign its delegate inside lazy variable initialization)

```
lazy var emailText: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    ...
    textView.delegate = self
    return textView
}()
```

---

Now, let's think about content. You have `UITextView` for inserting *email*. Since for inserting email is one line of text enough, use `UITextField` instead of your text view.

Then you can use text field's `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate method for dismissing keyboard after pressing *return key*

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: is it ok if you paste the entire code here for me? I get an error using the extention

Comment: 1. In extension of 'FirstPage'.  Expected declaration

Comment: @Sara where are you adding this extension? You have to add it on the same level as view controller

Comment: I am adding it at the end when I close the bracket of my class ( after the bracket)

Comment: You don't want to do this. Use a `UITextField` if you only want one line of text.

Comment: ok Got ya! Either way your method for the text view works. But I will try to switch to textfield now! Thank you all for helping me out. I appreciate it very much!!